# using currentTimeMillis for a method

Tags: java

I'm trying to record the time elapsed to run a certain method using currentTimeMillis, but am having trouble printing out the time...

```
public int foo(int n, int k) {
    if(n<=k)
        return 1;
    else
        return foo(n/k,k) + 1;
}
```

Where would I write in the lines for starTime, endTime, and the difference?

I tried throwing it in a different method:

```
public static long p3(int n, int k){
    long starTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    foo(n, k);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difference = endTime - starTime;
    return difference;
}
```

But the difference always appears as 0...

Answer (score 4):

If the method takes less than a milisecond to execute then yes the difference will be zero.

Then you need to  work with nanoseconds. System class has a method for these too:
[System#nanoTime();](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: I tested with `nanoTime` and it is *not* zero. +1

Comment: :- ) Glad i helped!
If you need anything else feel free to ask :- )

Comment: I realised, but you can still comment! :D

Comment: Also,  I've tried using nanoTime(), but for some reason the time actually drops the bigger I set my n!